# SharePoint 2013 Edit & Continue with .NET 4.5.1 and Visual Studio 2013

Tags: 2013, visual-studio, .net

Looking for an answer to this question since I heard of .NET 4.5.1, I've nearly given up the hope. Looks like no one has written anything about this anywhere. So now that 4.5.1 and VS2013 were released... Is it possible to switch SP to the new .NET Framework and use this long awaited feature, Edit & Continue, in SharePoint? It works in ASP.NET too.

**Update**: Just installing VS2013 and testing a previous solution did not work. Obviously you have to change SP to somehow use 4.5.1.

Creating a new SP Project targetting 4.5.1 does not work.

Comment: Have you tried it? After some research, it looks like that is possible, or at least Visual Studios 2013 is compatible with SharePoint 2013.

Comment: @Mike Yes I tried to edit the code in a simple SP Solution, but it told me that edit&continue is not available in x64. I guess you need to change SP so that it uses 4.5.1 because that is what you need for edit&continue to work afaik.

Comment: seriously? no one knows about or is interested in this life changing feature?

Comment: Add a bounty to it! You'll be sure to get some good answers, but this is something I have not personally have expertise in.

Comment: It seems as though edit and continue is strictly for 4.5.1, and sharepoint is strictly 4.5. Maybe the SP1 will include support for 4.5.1 and its features.

Comment: I would like to add bounty, but I am far from high enough to do this ;-) But you may be right, it simply won't work yet.

Answer (score 1):

You have limited edit and continue when developing apps for SharePoint. Changes to markup, JavaScript, and CSS will get pushed up to SharePoint when you save the source file. [Developing and Debugging Apps for SharePoint with Visual Studio 2013](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/SharePoint-Conference/2014/SPC261) shows an example of this around the 24 minute mark.

I don't think it's possible to get edit and continue to work for SharePoint solutions. If it was possible, it would require significant changes to the Visual Studio tooling. Right now, you update assemblies by rebuilding the solution package and deploying. This causes a reset of the IIS web application hosting SharePoint. I can't see any way this could happen during a Visual Studio debug session.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a standalone development environment? or are you deploying your app to the SharePoint production?

If this application is being deployed to SharePoint farm production environment, see if updating the .NET Framework in the SP farm from 4.5 to 4.5.1 or 4.5.2 will fix the issue.